# How can i use information from another table in a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried this, but it didn't work. I wanted to use the "valor" row to make this trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER valor_total ON Detalhe_Venda
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        DECLARE @vendaid INT
        DECLARE @produtoid INT
        DECLARE @qtd_produtos INT
        DECLARE @valor FLOAT

        SELECT @vendaid = venda_id, @produtoid = produto_id, @qtd_produtos = quantidadeprod
        FROM INSERTED

        SELECT @valor = valor
        FROM Produtos
        WHERE id = @produtoid

        UPDATE Venda 
        SET valortotal = valortotal + (@valor * @qtd_produtos)
        WHERE id = @vendaid
```

Comment: A far better approach is to simply calculate your sales total when needed and not duplicate the information (which now requires additional code and effort). You consider the addition of rows - but what should happen when rows are updated or deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding a lot of things about triggers in SQL Server.  The most important is that `INSERTED` is a *set* of rows, not a single row.

In fact, you can simplify your whole trigger to a single query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER valor_total ON Detalhe_Venda
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE v 
            SET valortotal = v.valortotal + (p.valor * i.quantidadeprod)
            FROM Venda v JOIN
                 Inserted i
                 ON v.id = i.venda_id JOIN
                 Produtos p
                 ON p.id = i.produtoid;
END;
```

EDIT:

SMore makes a good point.  Aggregation is probably desirable before the join:

```
CREATE TRIGGER valor_total ON Detalhe_Venda
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE v 
            SET valortotal = v.valortotal + ip.valor
            FROM Venda v JOIN
                 (SELECT i.venda_id,
                         SUM(p.valor * i.quantidadeprod) as valor
                  FROM Inserted i JOIN
                       Produtos p
                       ON p.id = i.produtoid
                  GROUP BY i.venda_id
                 ) ip
                 ON v.id = ip.venda_id
END;
```

Comment: We should assume that there is a 1:M relationship between Venda and Detalhe_Venda. Therefore, the code should be summing all related rows in the inserted table in order to add the correct number to the master (Venda) row.

Comment: @Smor . . . That is a really good point.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, this led me to a solution for the problem. i'm still a beginner, but learned a lot from you.